# Increment year by 2 for hsc and by 4 graduation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using dropdownlist 1 for ssc year, dropdownlist 2 for hsc year, and dropdownlist 3 for graduation year. Now I want to show hsc year as greater than the selected value of ssc year in dropdownlist 2 and graduation year as greater than the selected value of hsc year in dropdownlist 3. All dropdownlist have default items from 1980 to 2011. I tried autopostback method.

Comment: sharing your code would help us .

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `Code Behind` from below , but for your clarification sharing `Design code` as well.

Note : i have added only few years.(any how you have all years in your design code)

**Design Code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpListSSC" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpListSSC_SelectedIndexChanged"
EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" >
<asp:ListItem>1980</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>1981</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>1982</asp:ListItem>        
<asp:ListItem>1983</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>1984</asp:ListItem>

                                      <asp:ListItem>1985</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1986</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1987</asp:ListItem>

                                    <asp:ListItem>1988</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1989</asp:ListItem>

                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpListHSC" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpListHSC_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" >
                                   <asp:ListItem>1980</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1981</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1982</asp:ListItem>

                                    <asp:ListItem>1983</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1984</asp:ListItem>

                                      <asp:ListItem Value="10">1985</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="20">1986</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="50">1987</asp:ListItem>

                                    <asp:ListItem>1988</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1989</asp:ListItem>

                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpListGraduation" runat="server" 
                                    EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" >
                                  <asp:ListItem>1980</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1981</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1982</asp:ListItem>

                                    <asp:ListItem>1983</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1984</asp:ListItem>

                                      <asp:ListItem>1985</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1986</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1987</asp:ListItem>

                                    <asp:ListItem>1988</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>1989</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void drpListSSC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (drpListSSC.SelectedIndex + 2 < drpListHSC.Items.Count)
        drpListHSC.SelectedIndex = drpListSSC.SelectedIndex + 2;

        if (drpListHSC.SelectedIndex + 4 < drpListGraduation.Items.Count)
            drpListGraduation.SelectedIndex = drpListHSC.SelectedIndex + 4;
    }


    protected void drpListHSC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(drpListHSC.SelectedIndex + 4< drpListGraduation.Items.Count)
        drpListGraduation.SelectedIndex = drpListHSC.SelectedIndex + 4;
    }
```